# Importing a STEP file with multiple objects inside it

Tags: export, import

How do you import STEP files in Blender?

Usually I do it using FreeCAD; I open the STEP file and export it to STL, then import the STL file in Blender and it's all done.

That works flawlessly when there is only a single object/part/whatever you wanna call it, the only very small issue you can have is that sometimes the origin can get messed up, but fixing that is as simple as right clicking and going to Set Origin and selecting your favorite option.

But, when there are multiple objects present inside the STEP file, things change a lot. Converting the STEP file to STL gives you the whole structure, but it's no longer separate objects, it's all in one object, meaning you can't work on it anymore and it's just a brick that's just there. Note that I've tried with multiple files and programs, I've tried with the aforementioned FreeCAD, CAD Assistant, and several other tools online.

Also I've seen someone say [on here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126324/import-step-file-to-blender/166443#166443) that they've used CAD Assistant to convert the STEP file in .gltf/.glb, but importing a file with those extensions gave me these errors ([for .gltf](https://pastebin.com/z0yxuwEf) and [for .glb](https://pastebin.com/cWdVdi3R)), and I'm not very sure it doesn't do the same thing.

Am I doing it wrong? Like, am I omitting something, or am I using the wrong file format to export to? I'm not very experimented in this, I've only been using Blender, or any 3D software for that matter, for maybe three months very irregularly so go easy on me lol, I've just found simple and basic stuff that worked for me for now. And, don't recommend me that paid extension, since I'm pretty sure there's other alternatives too

Also, if anyone's asking what I'm trying to import in Blender, [here it is](https://www.gobilda.com/content/step_files/3209-0001-0003.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Andy, I hope you were able to find an easy, economical solution. I stumbled on your question 8 months later and wanted to share how I accomplished importing assemblies into Blender (while keeping parts separate) so that anyone else who finds this post later has at least one solution.

I imported the STEP file into Rhino, selected all, and performed ExplodeBlock. Then I exported to a COLLADA, which I was able to import directly into Blender. I realize that not everyone will have access to Rhino and that this solution isn't ideal for everyone, but it's one way to accomplish what you want.