# How keep the individual parts of a model? (converting STEP file for Blender with FreeCAD)

Tags: export, import

For context: [Import STEP file to Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126324/import-step-file-to-blender)

I just tried the FreeCAD way and it seems to work pretty well. Just one problem:

The imported STEP model is merged into one object. Is there a way to keep the individual parts of the model? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, the model will always be one object I'm afraid (as far as I know). In the question you linked here there is one answer suggesting to use CAD Assistant from Open Cascade. As I said in the comments there, when I use CAD Assistant to export as OBJ, the advantage is the resulting model is colored instead of a single default color. This way you can select mesh parts by material in Blender and separate them to get different objects. In _Edit Mode_ press A to select all, then P > Separate > By Material.

Comment: This works like a charm - thank you very much!