# Blender STEP support in the future?

Tags: file-format

I've come here to ask you about STEP files being supported by Blender.

To this day, the only way I found to import STEP files onto Blender is by using the STEPper addon. It's an old plugin made by Ambi before even the 3.0 version of Blender.
(link : https://ambient.gumroad.com/l/stepper)

This addon only works on windows though, and I think it would be a great step up if Blender could be able to import STEP files natively. After all, they are widely used in industrial 3D programs. Does anyone knows if this is gonna be a thing in the future?

Of course, I know extension support is a big deal and it's not gonna happen overnight, but I wanted to know if this was a subject or not.

Thanks in advance for your answers. :)

Comment: Here's some free alternatives  
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126324/import-step-file-to-blender/220579#220579

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. Only the devs would know if such feature is coming, we can only speculate. Considering STEP is a solid based CAD format, and Blender is a mesh based subdivision modeling animation software, I'd say the chance of native support is slim to none. Also there are good workarounds https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126324/import-step-file-to-blender